# Exclude webapp folder from Maven Build

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-plugin

I was trying to achieve a custom directory structure for my war with maven build.
Below is my build command used in pom.xml.

```
<build>
        <finalName>abc</finalName>
                 <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <mkdir dir="bin" />

                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp/</directory>
                                </resource>

                            </resources>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>bin</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Please find below the current directory structure of war file after unzip the war. Maven is including complete webapp directory under WEB-INF/Classes , But i want only java class files(ndaws directory). I have tried a lot of excluding techniques, But nothing works.
[image]

Comment: Please tell us about the "lot of excluding techniques" that you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I tryed alot of solutions. In the end I found one that solve my problem... It's a similiar case, but I need to exclude a folder inside the webapp.
I opened my war file using 7zip... The folder that I want to exclude were in the main page.
I used this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>myfolder/**</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Just change "myfolder" with the folder that you want to exclude.
If that is more than one folder, multiply this line.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, My changes in pom is not reflecting, war is being created from build folder under target.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

remove resource directory from **maven-resources-plugin**
and add warSourceDirectory to **maven-war-plugin**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or if using intelij and webapp folder marked 'resoures', select the folder.
open context menu.
**Mark Directory as** > **Unmark as Resources Root**